# Two iOS apps with same name in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, submit

I've two questions.

1. Can I submit two apps to the App Store with the same app name? I mean the name under the app icon on the home screen. I mean this:

[image: app name on home screen]

2. Can I submit two apps to the App Store with the same name on the App Store's information page? I mean this:

[image: app name in App Store]

And how is it with Android apps and the Google Play Store?

Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an app with the same name or similar name by doing the following things -

- Make a slight change by adding space, punctuation mark.
- By selecting Different Primary language when creating a new
  application.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have two apps on the App Store with the same display name. I don't know if apples app submission rules would cause them to reject two apps from the same company with the same name or not. That would be a question for Apple.

Comment: They aren't from the same company.

Comment: If it's a generic name, no problem. If it's a copyrighted name you can fill a complaint and the app gets usually pulled, if the dev doesn't change the name. The App Store name is usually more significant than the "screen" name on the device.

Comment: We can't create apps same name with same store setting langue. Difference language is  OK.